# Is it possible to share a connection pool between two different dataSources?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Is it somehow possible to share a connection pool between two different data sources? Both data sources use a different technology. Please note that the class used by `dataSource1` is `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` but the class used by `dataSource2` is `javax.sql.DataSource`.

```xml
<bean id="dataSource1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="testuser"/>
    <property name="password" value="test623"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2" class="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="testuser"/>
    <property name="password" value="test623"/>
</bean>
```

There are some queries that are too complicated to realize with Hibernate only that's why i'm trying to use JdbcTemplate as alternative. I use the following controller to test both technologies.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class DbAccessController {
    // Dependency injections
    @Autowired
    DbAccessService dbAccessService;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    /**
     * Query using CrudRepository with Hibernate. 
     * Works fine DataSource2.
     * 
     * @return Iterable containing a user list
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/queryHibernate")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<QisUser> getTestData() {
        Iterable<QisUser> qisUserList = dbAccessService.getAllQisUsers();
        return qisUserList;
    }
    
    /**
     * Query using JdbcTemplate. Trying to get this to
     * work with DataSource1 and the same connection pool
     * as DataSource2.
     * 
     * @return  String username
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/queryJdbc")
    public @ResponseBody String getUsername() {
        String username = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "SELECT * FROM QisUser WHERE NAME = 'Foo'", QisUser.class).getName();
        return username;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `javax.sql.DataSource` is an interface. I'm surprised that definition even works. However, neither use a connection-pool (a data source is a service provide by some data sources, these don't). If you want to use a connection pool, you should replace it with a definition that use a data source that provides connection pooling (e.g. from HikariCP, or Apache DBCP, etc). A word of advice: stop using Spring XML config and instead use the Java configuration.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your advice. My question is somewhat answered.